# Conditionally start a promise chain from a specific promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a promise chain that simplified looks like this:

```
readDB(file)
.then(parseQuery)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
.then(selectRandom)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
.then(requestTrailer)
  .catch((err) => {
    if(err == 'Got error: No results found') {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  })
    .then(renderMovie)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Basically I'm reading a list of movies from a file and passing them around so that I can find a trailer for the movie. What I wan't to do is on case of error, repeat the promise chain starting from `selectRandom` on, without having to `readDB` and `parseQuery`

Right now I have a working code but it defines the chain two times:

```
//I wrap the second round of promises in a function
selectMovie(){ 
    selectRandom(movies)
        .then(requestTrailer)
            .catch((err) => {
                if(err == 'Got error: No results found') {
                  selectMovie(); //Start the function again
                  throw new Error(err);
                }
            })
            .then(renderMovie)
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

//Now start the promise chain
readDB(file)
.then(parseQuery)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
.then(selectRandom)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
.then(requestTrailer)
  .catch((err) => {
    if(err == 'Got error: No results found') {
      selectMovie(); //Start second round
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  })
    .then(renderMovie)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Is there a more simple way of doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to DRY your code, but you partially did that so either I'm misunderstanding or you're missing the obvious. Couldn't you just replace part of the code at the bottom with `selectMovie()`?

Comment: Like readDB then parseQuery then selectMovie()? Should select movie have the return keyword? Or just as is?

Comment: I don't think `selectMovie()` _needs_ a return statement unless you want to add more promise chains afterwards, but it's usually a good idea to return _something_. But yeah, move it around, give it a try, and see what happens.

Comment: I was missing the obvious. It works perfectly

Comment: Haha, happens to everyone. Would you mind accepting my answer that I just added?

Comment: Sure thing. I’m still new to doing things here in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace .then(selectRandom) and everything after it by calling your selectMovie() function.